# div element just disappears as I add another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to mimic [canva](https://canva.com) using html, css and javascript.

I have come across an issue where div.search-field element just disappears as div.test is added to section.content. The purpose of adding div.test element to the section.content element is to test its scrolling functionality.

Here is the Html code:

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="search-field">
    <div class="search-field__bg"></div>
    <div class="search-field__front">
      <h2 class="search-field__heading">Design anything.</h2>
      <input type="search" class="search-field__input" placeholder='Try "Card"'>
      <svg class="navbar__icon-size-small">
        <use href="/img/svg/sprites.svg#icon-down-arrow"></use>
      </svg>
      <a class="search-field__link">Search field quotes</a>
      <a class="search-field__link">Search field quotes</a>
      <a class="search-field__link">Search field quotes</a>
      <a class="search-field__link">Search field quotes</a>
      <a class="search-field__link">Search field quotes</a>
      <a class="search-field__link">Search field quotes</a>
      <a class="search-field__link">Search field quotes</a>
      <a class="search-field__link">Search field quotes</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='test'>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test123</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test456</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test456</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test456</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test456</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is my css code:

```css
.search-field {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 99%;
  height: 34.4rem;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #85FFBD;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #85FFBD 0%, #FFFB7D 100%);
}

.search-field__bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 30vh);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(https://banner-static.canva.com/images/c4878dcc-0e7e-453f-adee-4c60971feb3d_20200523-DeskSpaceMint-Global-Desktop-2x.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  transform: translateY(calc(-1vh));
  object-fit: cover;
}

.search-field__front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-field__heading {
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.search-field__link {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is [My project on codepen](https://codepen.io/Beemo-007/pen/RwaRQjo?editors=1100). If you delete the whole div.test element or comment it out, the div.search-field should be shown properly.
Here is [My project on netlify](https://beemo.netlify.app).

So how do I fix this bug?

Comment: Please let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also if you link to a pen, make it the same as your question. Most people will not want to sift through 300 extra lines that don't resemble your Q.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your query:

```
html, body {    height: 100%;    }
```

but it just a solution you need to understand why it happened, this happened because your element is a **block-level** element which wraps up your whole content width and height width as a 100% but this is not the case with the height you need to specify the related to content to give height in percentages like the above body has given **100%**

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.search-field`. The element will be visible. You would have to change height of `.search-field__bg` (as you like of course). I would suggest you to use media queries if you want different dimensions for different screen sizes.

Comment: I don't understand, what have I done wrong here. overflow: hidden is supposed to hide the four squares of .search-field__bg because I set the border-radius: .8rem; to .search-field. Why overflow:hidden just remove the height of .search-field even though I have set height:34.4rem;